# How Do I Write A Redux Reducer?

Tags: reactjs, reducers, redux

I have a problem.
I have this tree-view(my InitialState). How must I write a reducer, 
that 'visible' property update, when i change it.
e.g I want to update the visible property, when i click on node.

```
email: {
    folderList: [ {
        name: 'Inbox',
        isSelected: false,
        isNested: true,
        visible: false,
        folderList: [ {
                name: 'SubFolder1',
                isNested: true,
                visible: false,
                folderList : [ {
                    name: 'SubFolder2',
                    isNested: true,
                    visible: false,
                    folderList: [ {
                            name: 'SubFolder3',
                            isNested: false,
                            visible: false
                    } ],
                    count: 5
                } ]
            }, {
                name: 'SubFolder1',
                isNested: false,
                visible: false
        } ],
        icon: 'icon-icon_inbox',
        count: 44
    }, {
        name: 'Outbox',
        isSelected: false,
        isNested: false,
        icon: 'icon-icon_outbox',
        count: 0,
        visible: false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should normalize the data so that the store looks like:

```
{
  folders: {
    1: {
      name: 'Inbox',
      ...
      folderList: [2,3]
    },
    2: {
      name: 'Folder 1',
      ...
      folderList: [6,7]
    },
    3: {
      name: 'Folder 2',
      ...
      folderList: [8,9]
    },
    4: {
      name: 'Outbox',
      ...
    },
   ...
}
```

Then when a node is clicked, your action creator will look like this:

```
folderClicked(folderid) {
  return { type: 'SELECT_FOLDER', payload: { folderId, visible: true } }
}
```

and your reducer would look like this

```
const initialState = normalizedListOfFolders;

export function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'SELECT_FOLDER':
    const { folderId, visible } = action.payload;
    return { ...state, [folderID]: { ...state[folderId], visible: true } }
  default:
    return state;
}
```

If you don't normalize, you're going to have to dig deep into the object with something like react's immutability helpers or immutable.js.